# Crystal reports - different detail section results on different servers

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, pdf-generation

I have a Crystal Reports report that simply has a Blob field(BinaryImage). The reports is in landscape and should simply show 1 label per page.
The problem I recently encountered was that setting the height of my details section has different results on different servers. The report is being generated from a website as a pdf. The code of the website is written in C#(backend) and typescript(frontend).

If I set the height of the detail section to 10 cm the report shows 1 label per page on my development pc(when run locally from code) and on our production server. However when the report is generated from a website hosted on our development server or acceptance server it shows 2 labels per page(1 on top and 1 at the bottom).

Setting the height of the section to 11cm gives the correct behavior on the development and acceptance server but gives an error locally and on the production server: "The page size was not large enough to format the contents of an object"

My development pc has Windows 10(64-bit), the servers have Windows Server 2016(64-bit) as OS.
I've tried comparing the registry keys of Crystal Reports on my pc and the development server but found nothing conclusive. Looking at potential printer options that could influence the behavior also showed no real results.

The report was made in Crystal Reports XI release 2 and all the servers(and my development pc) have "SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework(64-bit)" version 13.0.20.2399

The code is the same and so is the report. What could cause this different behavior?

[Section expert of details section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnndA.png)

**[edit]**

Here are 2 screenshots of the drivers installed on the DEV server and the PRD server:
[DEV Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBvPB.png)

[PRD Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfM0r.png)

The default printer is Microsoft Print To PDF. The driver for this printer is the same across all mentioned servers. The only real differences are the "Remote Desktop Easy print" driver, which has a lower version on the production server, and the "Send to Microsoft OneNote 16 Driver". The "uniFLOW Universal PclXL Driver" is only installed on the development server(and not on the  acceptance server) so it should not be the cause.

I did not succeed in trying to get the "Remote Desktop Easy Print" to use the same version as the production server but I did remove it once and the behavior did not change.

Comment: If you really want only one label per page, maybe it is enough to mark "new page before" in "section expert". Use the formula "recordnumber > 1" to avoid an initial blank page. But this is a work around, not really an answer. The difference may be due to printer configuration.

Comment: @heringer, though it indeed does not solve the issue it does provide the wanted result. I will use this to get the wanted result until a solution is found. I also think it has something to do with the printer settings/drivers/configuration/... but I unfortunatly don't know what exactly. Thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is usually tied to the print drivers installed on the individual computers. Insure that the servers all have the same print drivers install for whatever printer is set as the default.

Comment: i've updated the question. the drivers seem to be in order or at least they do not seem to be the problem.